# Android Didn't find class

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm following a Gif tutorial and created a custom class in my `wear/java/com.example.marcus.prog` folder called 'GIFView', but I can't reference this class from my XML layout. I've tried all sorts of combinations but I keep getting two errors about not finding the class.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marcus.prog/com.example.marcus.prog.AttackScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.example.marcus.prog.GIFView

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marcus.prog.GIFView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.marcus.prog-4/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

My XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:deviceIds="wear"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<prog.GIFView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the package and class name for what you refered in layout as `GIFView`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.example.marcus.prog.GIFView` instead of `prog03wear.GIFView` in your layout file.

Comment: sorry. that was just a typo while writing the question

Answer (score -1):

try this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`in your xml